# Border with different colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to achieve the layout below using bootsrap but without success.

Im using bootstrap nav, but do you know how to  have that gray border bottom below the links and when the active item is active have a border with a different color?

[image]

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/b6yqLc2d/

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-light-gray2">
  <div class="container nopadding py-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
        <h1 class="h5 text-center text-md-left mb-4 mb-lg-0 text-heading-blue font-weight-bold">Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-gray" href="#">Link</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-gray" href="#">Link</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-gray" href="#">Link</a>

        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Given your CSS, it seems you haven't really put much effort into trying. Just note that the `active` class is permanent unless you change it with JavaScript.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen he's using bootstrap i guess it's his only CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add border to `nav-link` without specifying color:

```css
.text-gray {
  color: gray;
}

.nav-link {
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="bg-light-gray2">
  <div class="container nopadding py-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
        <h1 class="h5 text-center text-md-left mb-4 mb-lg-0 text-heading-blue font-weight-bold">Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-gray" href="#">Link</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-gray" href="#">Link</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-gray" href="#">Link</a>

        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-gray{
  color:gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.active{

  border-bottom: 1px solid skyblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-link {
 border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
}
.nav-link.active {
 border-bottom-color: #007bff;
}
```

This is a solution you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a border that was more than one color, but each link can have its own border, so each border can have a different color.

Try adding this to the CSS in your jsfiddle:

```
a{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #ccc
}
a:hover{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #007bff;
}
a.active{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #007bff;
}
```

Comment: no a good idea to apply style to element, you will affect all the links of the page and not only the menu links

Comment: Good point.  This wasn't meant to be a production-ready solution, though.  Just a simple demonstration of the basic principle.